# Copy and Paste Files with Similar Extension using Batch File with recursive function

Tags: batch-file, recursion, copy

I'm trying to use the CMD Prompt to copy all my Excel files from all my subfolders into one aggregate folder. I've tried to use the following code:

```
 @echo off
    if exist aggregatexlsx (echo "it exists") else md aggregatexlsx
    for /R %%f in (*.xlsx) Do COPY %%f C:\Users\Username\Documents\Excel Test\aggregatexlsx
    exit /b
```

However, I receive the following response:
[image: response 1]

When I type in the for statement (with 1 `%f`) into the Command Prompt by itself, it returns me the following:
[image: response 2]

So my question is: if it calls the Excel documents (this is a small test case I have put together for a clean example), why is it struggling to copy and paste them in the new directory, `aggregatexlsx`?

Comment: You must quote source and destination: `COPY "%%~f" "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Excel Test\aggregatexlsx"`; otherwise, spaces and other special characters cause trouble...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your copy command is incorrect. It's `copy [file] [destination]`.

```
for /r "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Excel" %%f in (*.xlsx) do copy "%%~f" "Test\aggregatexlsx"
```

This is assuming you want to loop through C:\Users\Username\Documents\Excel

Comment: Thanks @aschimpfl and @Regejok! I got it to work courtesy of both your comments on the quotation marks. It worked!